# iOS WebSocket not connecting to Server using SocketRocket

Tags: ios, websocket, socketrocket

I'm creating a chat application whose WebSocket server is written in java.
For WebSocket client i'm using [SocketRocket](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket) library.

Everything works fine when i try to connect from `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.
But when i try to connect it using the public IP, it gives following error in `- (void) webSocket:(SRWebSocket *)_webSocket didFailWithError:(NSError *)error` method:

```
Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=57 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Socket is not connected"
```

Here is how i initialize the `SRWebSocket` object:

```
webSocket = [[SRWebSocket alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ws://IP_ADDRESS:8080/ChatWebSocket/chat/12345"]];  
// connects successfully when IP_ADDRESS = localhost or 127.0.0.1 
// gives 'Socket is not connected' error when IP_ADDRESS = some public IP address
```

I've also tried initializing `SRWebSocket` with `initWithURLRequest:`.

P.S i've also tested and verified that  the WebSocket server is accessible by its public IP address from a javascript code.

Therefor i think the issue is at the client end.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After almost 2 days of research, i finally realized that the problem was arising on simulator only.
When i tested the same code on an iPod touch, it worked like a charm! :)